# Download Twilio Recordings using C#

Tags: c#, twilio, webhooks, twilio-api

I am working on one small utility using Twilio API which intend to download the recording of the call as soon as call ends ( can be done using webhooks ? ). I am not sure if twilio supports this kind of webhooks or not.

The second approach that i have in mind is to create nightly job that can fetch all the call details for that day and download the recordings.

Can anyone suggest me which is the best approach to follow. I checked the [webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-webhook) but i am not sure if they provide the call ended event.

I would appreciate if anyone can provide me code sample on how to get the recordings for particular date and download them using C# from twilio.

Comment: Your utility is making outbound calls, which you record, right?

Comment: @AlexBaban I am only supposed to create something that downloads the recordings either as soon as the call ends or on nightly basis. My utility is not making any calls. But yes from somewhere they are making these calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get recording webhooks, but how you do so depends on how you record the call.

#### Using `<Record>`

Set a URL for the [`recordingStatusCallback` attribute on `<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback) and when the recording is ready you will receive a webhook with the link.

#### Using `<Dial>`

If you record a call from the [`<Dial>` verb using the `record` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record) set to any of `record-from-answer`, `record-from-ringing`, `record-from-answer-dual`, `record-from-ringing-dual` then you can also set a [`recordingStatusCallback`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-recording-status-callback).

#### Using `<Conference>`

If you [record a conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-record) then you can also set a [`recordingStatusCallback`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-recording-status-callback).

#### Recording an outbound dial

If you record the call by setting `Record=true` on an [outbound call made with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post) then you can also set a webhook URL by setting a [`RecordingStatusCallback` parameter in the request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#recording-status-callback-parameter).

### Retrieving recordings from the REST API

You can also use your second option and call the REST API to retrieve recordings. To do so, you would use the [Recordings List resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#list). You can restrict this to the recordings before or after a date using the [list filters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#list-get-filters).

Here is a quick example of how you would use the [Twilio C# library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp) to fetch recent recordings:

```
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "AC81ebfe1c0b5c6769aa5d746121284056";
    string AuthToken = "your_auth_token";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var recordings = twilio.ListRecordings(null, null, null, null);

    foreach (var recording in recordings.Recordings)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(recording.Duration);
      // Download recording.Uri here
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: I have a question. How and where can i configure the <record>  call back ? I am pretty new to twilio so how do i use record feature ? my account shows no recordings are available right now.

Comment: Are you recording a message from a caller or trying to record a whole call between 2 (or more) people?

Comment: This is a good article on the various ways you can record a call: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132867-Recording-a-phone-call-with-Twilio

Comment: after adding twilio c# sdk i am getting this error. http://prntscr.com/edlgzp can you please suggest a solution. ?

Comment: Where did you get `Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient` from? When you are `using Twilio` you can just call `new TwilioRestClient` like above. Have you tried the code from my answer?

Comment: how can i access the paged recordings ? The code which you have provided returns 50 recordings and then it has the pagination. How to access the other recordings ?

Comment: Paging information actually comes back with the [API responses](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information). You can change the page size, using the `PageSize` parameter and request further pages with the URLs returned.

Comment: i am trying to access the paged records like this. twilio.ListRecordings(null, null, recordings.Page + 1, 50) but it throws exception that paging token is missing. how do i pass pagingtoken ?

Comment: So, apparently the v4 version of the C# library doesn't support pagination. Can I recommend you upgrade to the [latest version 5 that was released this week](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/next-generation-csharp-helper-library-release.html).

Comment: yes. Just realized that and upgraded the version. i will post my solution as answer for others to refer.